# TestNGException

Tags: java, eclipse, mocking

I'm getting the below error when I run my test classes. Please advise how to fix this issue?

```
Cannot find class in classpath: za.co.woolworths.core.droplet.DeliverySlotTableDropletTest
at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.loadClass(XmlClass.java:76)
at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.init(XmlClass.java:68)
at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.<init>(XmlClass.java:54)
at org.testng.xml.TestNGContentHandler.startElement(TestNGContentHandler.java:523)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:17)
at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:10)
at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:170)
at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:305)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:88)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:202)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:173)
```

Comment: Does Eclipse have the class path properly set up? Does it report any problems in the Package Explorer or Problems View?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try the -testjar flag while running the test cases? Or -testclass flag in case you dont have a jar file?

Try bundling your test cases in a jar and then use the -testjar flag.

Comment: Im running this test on Eclipse not on the command line and all of my test cases are failing on the above error.

Comment: Did you create the launch properly? http://testng.org/doc/eclipse.html#eclipse-create-launch